# When Windows 7 tells me 'Consider changing your password', how long have I got until password expiry?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, group-policy

I'm on a corporate desktop, running Windows 7. We have a password expiration policy which mandates that passwords are changed every month or so (not sure of the exact period). When password expiry time approaches, I get an icon in the notification area like so:

[image: Keys in notification area with Consider changing your password tooltip]

Right-clicking this notification does nothing; left-clicking it makes it disappear.

How long before password expiry time does this notification appear?

If the time can vary, how can I find out what it's set to? (bearing in mind that I am very much a **non**-administrator on both machine and domain)

Comment: This is configurable by your IT staff.  We can't possible know what their policy is if you don't know.  If you ignore that message eventually it will start telling you how many days you have.

Comment: @Ramhound "eventually it will start telling you how many days you have" - not in my experience. Anyway, I've received an answer that works.

Comment: I work on a workstation 5-days a week where every 90 days I am told my password will expired in X Days and then proceeds to count down until it either expires or I change it.  Its possible your IT staff have configured your domain NOT to do that.

Comment: This also applies to Windows 10. And like @AakashM, the number of days till expiry is not displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand you are on corporate Windows Domain. The number of days before password expiration is a subject of domain policy, by default 42 days and it let you know 14 days before expiration, as far as I remember correctly.

This [link](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/AdminTips/ActiveDirectory/Findingoutwhenyourdomainpasswordwillexpire.html) advises to use the following command to get the number of days before expiration:

```
net user %USERNAME% /domain
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get a message:

```
Consider changing your password
Your password expired in x days.
```

Now you have a "x" days to change your password.

After this time (at day x+1) you'll get a message:

```
Your password has expired and must be changed
```

and you can't login without to change the old password.

Comment: But I *don't* get any message with a number of days in it. Where should I expect to see this?

Comment: @AakashM - At the configurable date in time.  Your IT staff can provide that information.